# Forcibly included header not found

Tags: c++, gcc, include, precompiled-headers

I'm trying to set up precompiled headers in a large C++ project compiled with GCC 5.4.

There is a file "PrecompiledHeaders.h", which includes all the other relevant headers. I've added the compile flag `-include PrecompiledHeaders.h`, but when compiling, the header is not found:

```
cc1plus: fatal error: PrecompiledHeaders.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/Project.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/Project.dir/NetworkGameState.cpp.o' failed
```

But I'm sure it exists, in the same directory as all other `h` and `cpp` files. What's more, manually adding `#include "PrecompiledHeaders.h"` to the top of "NetworkGameState.cpp" does not produce an error.
What could go wrong?

This is a CMake, out-of-source build, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely an issue with the path. From [the GCC 5.4 manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.4.0/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#Preprocessor-Options) (emphasis mine):

> `-include` *file*
>   Process *file* as if `#include "file"` appeared as the first line of the primary source file. **However, the first directory searched for *file* is the preprocessor's working directory *instead of* the directory containing the main source file.** If not found there, it is searched for in the remainder of the `#include "..."` search chain as normal.

You need to either supply the full (relative or absolute) path to the header as the argument of the `-include` flag, or add its parent directory to the search chain using e.g. `-I` or `-iquote`.

Comment: Ah, I read that, but read it wrong. I thought it would do that first, and then continue with the source file's directory, and the rest. That must be it then